# jQuery Parse date - '2013-12-29T18:30:00.000Z in format of dd/mm/yy

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have getting date in format as I specify above but I want to parse date into `dd/mm/yy`. I used `$.datepicker` to parse date like

```
searchVal = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy', $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.tttZ', searchVal));
```

The error reported from `jquery-ui.min.js is`: **Missing number at position 0**

Does anyone know how to do this???

Comment: Which jquery version are you using??. Latest version have fix this bug i guess.

Comment: 'Missing number at position nn' if format indicated a numeric value that is not then found

Comment: My jQuery version is 1.8.3 & jQuery UI version is 1.9.2

Comment: The [datepicker API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) says "**MM - month name long**" and you are matching *yyyy-MM-dd*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [datepicker widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) documentation:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( 2007, 1 - 1, 26 ) );
```

Maybe you should change the javascript into the following:

```
searchVal = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/MM/yyyy', new Date('2013-12-29T18:30:00.000Z')));
```

Comment: I implement your solution but code giving date as `30/12/20132013`

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [jquery Datepicker docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate), there is no yyyy format token (only y or yy). For a four digit year you'll want the "yy" option. example:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate( "yy-mm-dd", "2007-01-26" );
```

If after fixing that it still gives you an error, I'd start with a simpler format (maybe yy-mm-dd) for the parseDate and add to it until I reach the problematic part.

As a side note, if your using the datepicker just for date manipulation and parsing you might want to take a look at moments.js (It's very good):
http://momentjs.com/